# postgresSQL pgadmin 4 query

Tags: postgresql, ddl

```
if
Select EXISTS (
  select FROM information_schema.tables 
   WHERE  table_schema = 'public'
   AND    table_name   = 'Backups'
   );
Then
INSERT INTO Backups
SELECT * FROM dd;

Else 
CREATE TABLE Backups (LIKE dd INCLUDING ALL);
INSERT INTO Backups
SELECT * FROM dd;

end if;
```

In this code first I am checking 'if' the table named 'Backup' is exist or not if exist copy data from table 'dd' to backup and if not exist create a table with name 'Backup' like 'dd' and insert data from 'dd' to 'Backup'. but it showing error near "if" can some one tell why it happens

Answer (score 1):

`IF` can only be used inside procedural code (PL/pgSQL) and that can only be used in stored functions, procedures or an anonymous PL/pgSQL `DO` block.

But you don't need an IF or even PL/pgSQL for this.

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists Backups (LIKE dd INCLUDING ALL);

INSERT INTO Backups
SELECT * FROM dd;
```

If you want to make sure the backups table is empty, just add

```
truncate table backups;
```

right after the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: but i have one more query that , actually i am trying to create a trigger which runs when ever we perform insert or update on any table from which a backup of that table is created...but how can we capture the name of table on which we perform insert or update in query from which we don't have to hard code the name of that table as we doing above "dd".

Comment: for example here:

CREATE TABLE if not exists Backups (LIKE dd INCLUDING ALL);

INSERT INTO Backups
SELECT * FROM dd; -------->here in place of 'dd' i have to capture the name of table on which i m doing insert or update at runtime

Answer (score 0):

That is not an SQL statement, but PL/pgSQL code.

There is also a bug: It should be

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT ...)
```

instead of

```
IF SELECT EXISTS (SELECT ...)
```

You could run that code as a `DO` SQL statement:

```
DO
'BEGIN
   /* your code goes here */
END;';
```